# Как забанить участника на сервере из-за сообщения с плохим словом?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Пишу бота Discord. Участок кода:

```py
banMsg = ["Матерок", "Матерок1", "Матерок2", "Матерок3", "Матеро4"]

@Bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    for i in banMsg:
        if i in msg.content:
            await Bot.ban(user.msg.message.author)
#            await Bot.delete_message(msg)
    await Bot.process_commands(msg)
```

Когда пользователь введёт слово, которое есть в списке `banMsg` - ничего не будет, только ошибка в cmd:

> Ignoring exception in on_message Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "C:\Users\Матвей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py",
> line 307, in _run_event     yield from getattr(self, event)(*args,
> **kwargs)   File "BOT.py", line 17, in on_message     await Bot.ban(user.msg.message.author) NameError: name 'user' is not defined

Что нужно ввести в

```py
await Bot.ban(user.msg.message.author)
```

(7 строка кода), что бы бот нормально забанил участника?

Comment: Текст ошибки-то напишите. А то так сложно что-то сказать.

Comment: Вот ```Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Матвей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "BOT.py", line 17, in on_message
    await Bot.ban(user.msg.message.author)
NameError: name 'user' is not defined```

Comment: Попробуйте у себя пожалуйста... Я как не менял - ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

В этой строке

```
await Bot.ban(user.msg.message.author)
```

вы используете перемённую user, которой у вас в этой функции попросту нет. Я не знаком с discord-py, но по общей логике вам нужно просто заменить строчку на

```
await Bot.ban(msg.message.author)
```

P.S. Учитесь разбирать сообщения об ошибке. У вас там прямым текстом написано, что у вас не так.